# apache karaf dev:watch command doesn't work

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, watch

As far as I've read, the dev:watch command of apache karaf should help developing osgi bundles in such way that I don't have to manually update a bundle everytime I make changes to the sourcecode of that bundle.

I tried this, with one simple bundle which only consists of a Activator class.
I am using maven for development.

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

public void start(BundleContext context) {
    System.out.println("Starting the bundle");
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) {
    System.out.println("Stopping the bundle");
}
}
```

I installed the bundle using the karaf command:

```
osgi:install mvn:my.groupId/my.artifactId
```

then I started the bundle using `osgi:start <id of my bundle>`

then I started monitoring for this bundle `using dev:watch --start <id of my bundle>`

> Karaf tells me that it monitors my bundle.

Then I wanted to test if the bundle will be updated automatically if I make changes to the source code and rebuild my bundle.
So I changed the `System.out.println()'s` of the activator class and built my rebuild my bundle using `mvn clean install`.

Shouldn't the bundle updates itself now?  When I take a look at the karaf console I see no changes until I update the bundle manually using osgi:update (which I want to avoid, using dev:watch) ...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some hours I found the source of error.
Even if the bundle is already a SNAPSHOT version, it is not sufficient to install the bundle using `osgi:install mvn:<groupID>/<artifactID>` but you have to use the `<version>` too in the bundle URL: `osgi:install mvn:<groupID>/<artifactID>/<version>` ,where `<version>` corresponds to the version tag specified in the pom.xml. It has to be a snapshot version like "1.0-SNAPSHOT".

Answer (score 0):

Is the maven version a SNAPSHOT? dev:watch only works for snapshots as fixed versions are not expected to change.

Comment: hi, how can i configure that explicitly? The generated Jar in the target folder is called like bla.blubb.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar so I guess this is a snapshot version?!

Comment: Yes this sounds like a snapshot version and so it should work. Did you use mvn install? Install deploys the jar into the local maven repo. This is necessary as karaf only watches the local repo not the target folder. You should also check that you use the default location for the maven repo or configure your special repo location in karaf.

Comment: yes i am using mvn install to build the bundle. The maven project is dropped into C:/users/user/.m2/repository where i can find the jar too. After that i install the bundle with "osgi:install <mvnpath>" and instruct karaf to monitor the bundle using "dev:watch <id>". That's all. Is it right that the bundle should immediately update itself (like i would call osgi:update on it) after i call mvn clean update again on a changed bundle project? or am i missing any intermediate step?

Comment: What you do sounds completely right. One last idea. What do you use as <id> in dev:watch? Can you try dev:watch * ?

Comment: after i have installed the bundle i use osgi:list to get the id of the bundle. The bundle is in state "active" and has the id 113. so i am using "dev:watch 113" which outputs "Watched URLs/IDs: 113". When i use "dev:watch *" it also does not work... :(

Comment: The only thing I can think of is: When i take a look at the help to the dev:watch command there it says: "if you run > dev:watch *
It will actually monitor all bundles that have a location matching mvn:* that have '-SNAPSHOT' in their url." Well, i don't have a "-SNAPSHOT" string in my URL itself. The URL of my bundle is simply: "mvn:com.bundles/com.bundles.testbundle" following the pattern mvn:<groupID>/<artifactID>

Comment: okay! and exactly THAT was the problem :D I installed my bundle like "osgi:install mvn:<groupID>/<artifactID>" instead of "osgi:install mvn:<groupID>/<artifactID>/<version>" where version is 1.0-SNAPSHOT according to the version tag in the pom file. Now it works perfectly. :D thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem. After some hours I found annother the source of error.

I work on Windows and I had `<localRepository>D:\m2repo</localRepository>` inside my settings.xml

Maven was OK with that but BundleWatcher doesn't.
Worked after change to `D:/m2repo` (nottice: unix-style forward slash).